# Angular9 - open part of reactive form as modal

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular9 Reactive Form for an Order placement. Form is a pretty large, so some parts of the form are operated as modal actions. For example: you select a Customer directly in the form, but when you want to edit Billing address, you do that through modal window.

However, either Customer or Billing address are part of the same instance of a Reactive Form.

Tricky part are modal actions. If user opens Billing address modal window, there are two buttons (Apply or Cancel). I want to update Billing address only when user hits Apply. This is not happening now because modal window operates with particular FormGroup 'BillingAddress' of the single instance of Reactive Form, so values are updated ad hoc while typing in modal window.

My idea is to create new, reduced, Reactive Form instance in Billing address modal, loaded from "the primnary form" and if user hits Apply then take its value and patch it to primary form.

Is there any other recommended workaround or "angular way" how to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need pass to modal the "data", in "ok" make a patchValue, you can use a setter to create the form

e.g. using [ng-bootstrap modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component)

You modal is like

```
  <div [formGroup]="form">
     <input formControlName="name">
     <input formControlName="surname">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" 
        (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Close click')">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" 
        (click)="activeModal.close(this.form.value)">Ok</button>
```

See that with NgbModal, the button "OK" close using `close` function and pass as argument the value of the form while "Cancel" using `dismiss`

Your modal component has as variable form (a formGroup) and a `@Input() data` that is a setter

```
  form:FormGroup
  @Input() set data(value)
  {
    value=value || {name:null,surname:null}
    this.form=new FormGroup({
       name:new FormControl(value.name),
       surname:new FormControl(value.surname)
    })
  }
```

The last you need, when open the modal, pass the data yo the reference and, when close use set Path

```
 //imagine your form is like
 form:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    customer:new FormGroup({
       name:new FormControl("Name"),
       surname:new FormControl("Surname")
    })
  })


 open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent)

    //see you pass as data "this.form.value.customer"
    modalRef.componentInstance.data = this.form.value.customer;

    modalRef.result.then(
      (result) => {

       //see you use setPath (or setValue)
         this.form.get('customer').patchValue(result)

    }, (reason) => {
      
    });
  }
```

A [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phwmab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-component.ts)

**Update** Well is a bit difficult to maintenance some like this because you need create the same form in modal and in main component. You can get out the creation of the forms in a file like

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

export  abstract class Model{
  public static getCustomer=getCustomer
}

function  getCustomer(value):FormGroup {
    value = value || { name: null, surname: null };
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(value.name),
      surname: new FormControl(value.surname)
    });
  }
```

Then, you import the abstract class Model

```
import {Model} from './model-form'
```

and create the forms like

```
//in main component
form:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    customer:Model.getCustomer({name:"Name",surname:"Surname"})
})

//in modal
@Input() set data(value)
{
    this.form=Model.getCustomer(value)
}
```